# Word choice: “won't” or “wouldn't”

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Which one is correct?

- Usually I *won't* photograph birds with man-made objects (such as utility poles), but that was an unusual day.
- Usually I *wouldn't* photograph birds with man-made objects (such as utility poles), but that was an unusual day.

I am trying to express my strategy or usual habit, so what would be correct "won't" or "wouldn't"?

Comment: For the past habit, would/wouldn't can be used. If it's a permanent or usual habit, simple present tense can also be used. "Usually I don't photograph...."

Answer (score -1):

Your second bullet version is correct because "wouldn't" goes with "was" (past tense).

Also, "I won't" means "I'm not willing to."  For example:

> I won't photograph children in embarrassing situations because it feels exploitative.